# Test Class help: for Approval Process

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am fetching all the approval comments from an `after update` trigger. But in my test class I don't know how to cover the `ProcessSteps`. My Approval Process has 2 step approvers.

```
List<Planner__c > listtp=[
    SELECT Name, Approved_Amount__c,
        (SELECT IsPending, ProcessInstanceId, TargetObjectId, StepStatus, OriginalActorId,
            ActorId, RemindersSent, Comments, IsDeleted, CreatedDate, CreatedById
        FROM ProcessSteps ORDER BY createdDate DESC LIMIT 1)
    FROM Planner__c WHERE id =: Trigger.new[0].id
];
```

**I am not able to cover inner sqol query (Processsteps)**

```
 for(vepl_TravelPlanner__c c : listtp)
              {
                for (ProcessInstanceHistory ps : c.ProcessSteps)
                {

    // Get the Comment section from approval Object.
                       If(ps.Comments!=null){

//My logic.
    }
    }
```

**so can someone guide me how to use ProcessSteps.**

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similiar issue a while ago, and used this solution to run my tests.

First, you need to create a listing of records of whatever type you need (In your case, `Planner__c`), and insert them.

```
Planner__c testPlanner = new Planner__c();
...
insert testPlanner;
```

Then, you need need to submit them as a proper user (someone who would be submitting them normally).

```
User submitter = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE ... AND IsActive = true LIMIT 1];

System.runAs(submitter) {
    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest r = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();

    r.setObjectId(testPlanner.Id);

    Approval.process(r);
}
```

Now, you should have the records submitted, and the various approval process records should be inserted. You should be able to query them, and use `System.runAs` and the `ActorID` to approve, reject, or any other test functionality you may need.

Answer (score 1):

this is a known issue if you are having a sub query(on ProcessSteps) based on a object and when using the same concept in test class , sub query will be returned as null, so salesforce is very well aware of this , here is the link for voting in case issue affects similar users
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SWMFAA4